# Book suggestion for Java web application testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, web-applications, automated-tests

Could you recommend some books on Java web application testing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best JUnit Book available (IMHO) http://www.manning.com/rainsberger/

Comment: Looks like the book is old. How about JUnit in Action?

Comment: JUnit in Action is also an old book, even older than JUnit Recipes. Both are valuable if you can afford it. Because they are older, you should be able to get them at a discount.  Check out Swaptree.com to trade books, I've made 50+ trades there for old computer books.  What I like about JUnit Recipes is the very specific scenarios for testing in container resources, and a lot of mock object testing scenarios to test in container resources. Also a good resource for XMLUnit info.